# Save without dialog box then open newly created file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to save a range from Excel to a separate CSV file.

I found code that works. I want to make two modifications.

I'm not interested in the dialog box that opens asking me to save the file.
It should save in the current folder.

Also, is there a way to automatically open the newly created CSV file after it's created?

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Public Sub ExcelRowsToCSV()
 
  Dim iPtr As Integer
  Dim sFileName As String
  Dim intFH As Integer
  Dim aRange As Range
  Dim iLastColumn As Integer
  Dim oCell As Range
  Dim iRec As Long
 
  Set aRange = Range("D1:V39")
  iLastColumn = aRange.Column + aRange.Columns.Count - 1
  
  iPtr = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")
  sFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, iPtr - 1) & Format(Date, " mmm dd, yyyy ") & ".csv"
  sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=sFileName, FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
  If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
  Close
  intFH = FreeFile()
  Open sFileName For Output As intFH
  
  iRec = 0
  For Each oCell In aRange
    If oCell.Column = iLastColumn Then
      Print #intFH, oCell.Value
      iRec = iRec + 1
    Else
      Print #intFH, oCell.Value; ",";
    End If
  Next oCell
   
  Close intFH
  
  MsgBox "Finished: " & CStr(iRec) & " records written to " _
     & sFileName & Space(10), vbOKOnly + vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new workbook, copy data and save as CSV rather than `open/print` csv. Avoid reopening the csv file.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExcelRowsToCSV()
    Dim iPtr As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim newWK As Workbook
    Set aRange = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D1:V39")
    iPtr = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")
    sFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, iPtr - 1) & Format(Date, " mmm dd, yyyy ") & ".csv"
    Set newWK = Workbooks.Add
    With aRange
        newWK.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    newWK.SaveAs Filename:=sFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
    MsgBox "Finished: " & CStr(aRange.Rows.Count) & " records written to " _
        & sFileName & Space(10), vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is it possible to default save to a specific location on the c drive?  Just found out, our program does not load from the shared drive.  Thank you

Comment: Tried adding ChDir "C:\temp"  but does not seem to work.

Comment: `sDir = "C:\temp"
    iPtr = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")
    sfilename = sDir & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, iPtr - 1) & Format(Date, " mmm dd, yyyy ") & ".csv"`

Comment: Hi taller_ExcelHome, I added Dim sDir As String and got it to worked.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, iPtr - 1) & _
            Format(Date, " mmm dd, yyyy ") & ".csv"
```

will save to the same folder as ActiveWorkbook (provided that workbook has been saved somewhere)

`Workbooks.Open(sFileName)` will open the saved file in excel.