# VBA Code to save sheet to .CSV file producing empty files

Tags: excel, vba, csv, adodb

I have existing code to create .CSV files, but a lot of times, the .CSV files end up being empty but the VBA code runs with no issue. I'm trying to find a fix or a better way to create .CSV files from Excel worksheets.

```
' Create .CSV assumption files
Public Sub Create_File(ByVal fldr As String, ws As String, fname As String, cnn As ADODB.Connection)
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim fso As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fldr & fname & ".csv", True)

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "select * from [" & ws & "$];", cnn

    'determine what the field names are
    strFields = ""
    For z = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        strFields = strFields & rs.Fields(z).Name & ","
    Next z

    'last field has a "," after so remove it
    strFields = Left(strFields, Len(strFields) - 1)

    txtFile.WriteLine strFields

    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
    Else
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            txtFile.Write rs.GetString(adClipString, , ",", vbCrLf, "")
        Loop
    End If

    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please try to add `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` before `rs.Open`. btw, The goal of your code is convert a worksheet into csv with a little change on headers. [Workbook].SaveAs is a tidy approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100468/modify-macro-to-eliminate-dialog-box-and-open-newly-created-file/77101274

Comment: When the CSV is empty is the recordset also empty?

Comment: What is the variable `ws` ? Does it need to be a valid sheet name and the sheet has focus? Where would you see the error message if not?

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, it's odd because the sheet it's trying to pull from is definitely populated but i think rs is empty. Something is causing VBA not to pull the data from the worksheet. Taller_ExcelHome, I will try your solution today and see how it works.

Comment: You could try `rs.MoveFirst` after you open the recordset.